how to delete old class file referenced in django migration
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
dependencies = [
    ("buckets", "0001_auto_20230420_2018"),
]

operations = [
    #  Delete existing tables
    migrations.RunSQL(
        sql=buckets.my_models.models.RefObjModel.get_create_table_sql(),
        reverse_sql=migrations.RunSQL.noop,
    ),

above is sample code how we have migration files, there are many migration where this kind of code is written.
Question: we have to remove RefObjModel, how we should be doing it, what is preferred approach. If we are deleting the class file/code application run is failing as it tries to run all the migration file and unable to find referenced class.
If we delete the references from all the migration files manually, does it create any problem in production deployment/application
